# creating a java segment code

Tags: java

```
segment of code: 

int x, y = 34, z = 19, w=11;

swtich (x) {
    case 1:     y += 4;
        z -= w;
        break;
    case 2:   w = (x++)*(--y);
        break;
    case 3: w = (--x)*(++y);
        break;
    case 4:   y -=7;
    case 5:   z *= 2;
        break;
    default:    w = (++x)*(++y);
}
System.out.println(“x = “ + x + “ y = “ + y + “  z = “ +  z + “  w = “ + w);
```

can someone help me fix up this code please?

Comment: what is this code suppose to do ?

Comment: There are a number of potential problems I can see but for starters, you need to tell us what it's supposed to do otherwise we can't help you.  For instance, what I see as "potential problems" are only problems if the program isn't supposed to do that, so we can't help you until you tell us what the goal is.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, you forgot to put `break;` on  `CASE 4`. Then if x is local variable, you forgot to initialize it. And how do you plan to input the x?

EDIT: It's working on my PC.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int x=0, y = 34, z = 19, w = 11;

        x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(x)); //this is how i input x  

        switch (x) {
            case 1:
                y += 4;
                z -= w;
                break;
            case 2:
                w = (x++) * (--y);
                break;
            case 3:
                w = (--x) * (++y);
                break;
            case 4:
                y -= 7;
                break;
            case 5:
                z *= 2;
                break;
            default:
                w = (++x) * (++y);
        }
        System.out.println("x = " + x + "y = " + y + "  z = " + z + "  w = " + w);
    }
}
```

illegal character: \8220 or \8221: You used Unicode 8220 (aka \u291c, 0x291c, “, left quote) or ... something of the form usually when you Copy Paste a code... Type again the System.out.println line especially the quote ("), maybe you copy paste it and it is in different form... For more details about errors check out [this site](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/compileerrormessages.html)

Comment: on the system.out.println i get an error illegal char 8220. how can i fix it

Answer (score 1):

`case 4` needs a `break` (unless you intended case 4 to "fall through" to `case 5`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has smart quote characters (`“`), which aren't normal quotes and are not recognized by the Java language.

Change the `“` characters to `"`.